# Complex functions decomposition

Tags: complex-analysis

I know that a complex number can be written as a product its modulus and a phase.

Can the same be applied to a function of a complex variable?

Comment: Do you mean if a complex function also can be written as a product of its modulus and a phase?

Comment: Yes. Is it possible generally?

Comment: If it is a complex function where the input is a real variable, it may be possible, but if the complex function has a complex input, I think the algebra will stand in the way. Usually, in case of a complex function, it is split in a real part and a imaginary part (both functions where the input is real), but that then becomes a sum! So I doubt that it is possible what you are looking for. I hope somebody else can share some input here.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can. Complex function is also a complex scalar. The general form of a function $f(z)$ can then be written as
$$f(z)=\Re f(z)+i~\Im f(z)=\sqrt{f(z)\bar f(z)}\exp\{\arctan\frac{\Im f(z)}{\Re f(z)}\}$$